# Sum of last values of a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a new column where the values are the sum of the last 14 values of column atr1, How can I do it?

I tried

```
col = a.columns.get_loc('atr1')
a['atrsum'] = a.iloc[-14:,col].sum()
```

But I get only a fixed value in the new column. Dataframe below as reference.

```
   time             open    high    low     close   volume          atr1
0   1620518400000   1.6206  1.8330  1.5726  1.7663  8.830913e+08    NaN
1   1620604800000   1.7662  1.8243  1.5170  1.6423  7.123049e+08    0.3073
2   1620691200000   1.6418  1.7791  1.5954  1.7632  5.243267e+08    0.1837
3   1620777600000   1.7633  1.8210  1.5462  1.5694  5.997101e+08    0.2748
4   1620864000000   1.5669  1.9719  1.5000  1.9296  1.567655e+09    0.4719
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
360 1651622400000   0.7712  0.8992  0.7677  0.8985  2.566498e+08    0.1315
361 1651708800000   0.8986  0.9058  0.7716  0.7884  3.649706e+08    0.1342
362 1651795200000   0.7884  0.7997  0.7625  0.7832  2.440587e+08    0.0372
363 1651881600000   0.7832  0.7858  0.7467  0.7604  1.268089e+08    0.0391
364 1651968000000   0.7605  0.7663  0.7254  0.7403  1.751395e+08    0.0409
```

Comment: When you sum 14 values you just get 1 value. The new column will be filled with this 1 particular value. So unless you meant to do something different, you will get a fixed value in the new column

Comment: @adsjr, did the solution addressed the question?

Comment: @Naveed it did not as explained below.

Comment: @onyambu yes, I want a single value as a rolling sum, but as it is rolling the values should differ

Comment: there is a difference between rolling sum and summing the 14 last values. use `rolling(14).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use expanding function of pandas

14 is the number of days, followed by the column you like to sum

```
a.expanding(14)['atr1'].sum()
```

I must be missing something in the question, ,my apologies.
I just used the data you shared and used the 2 previous days and this is the  result

```
df['atrsum'] = df['atr1'].expanding(2).sum()
```

```
    id       time          open     high    low     close   volume         atr1     atrsum
0   0        1620518400000  1.6206  1.8330  1.5726  1.7663  8.830913e+08    NaN     NaN
1   1        1620604800000  1.7662  1.8243  1.5170  1.6423  7.123049e+08    0.3073  NaN
2   2        1620691200000  1.6418  1.7791  1.5954  1.7632  5.243267e+08    0.1837  0.4910
3   3        1620777600000  1.7633  1.8210  1.5462  1.5694  5.997101e+08    0.2748  0.7658
4   4        1620864000000  1.5669  1.9719  1.5000  1.9296  1.567655e+09    0.4719  1.2377
5   360     1651622400000   0.7712  0.8992  0.7677  0.8985  2.566498e+08    0.1315  1.3692
6   361     1651708800000   0.8986  0.9058  0.7716  0.7884  3.649706e+08    0.1342  1.5034
7   362     1651795200000   0.7884  0.7997  0.7625  0.7832  2.440587e+08    0.0372  1.5406
8   363     1651881600000   0.7832  0.7858  0.7467  0.7604  1.268089e+08    0.0391  1.5797
9   364     1651968000000   0.7605  0.7663  0.7254  0.7403  1.751395e+08    0.0409  1.6206
```

Result with Rolling sum

```
df['atrsum'] = df['atr1'].rolling(2).sum()
```

```
    id      time           open     high    low     close   volume         atr1     atrsum
0   0       1620518400000   1.6206  1.8330  1.5726  1.7663  8.830913e+08    NaN     NaN
1   1       1620604800000   1.7662  1.8243  1.5170  1.6423  7.123049e+08    0.3073  NaN
2   2       1620691200000   1.6418  1.7791  1.5954  1.7632  5.243267e+08    0.1837  0.4910
3   3       1620777600000   1.7633  1.8210  1.5462  1.5694  5.997101e+08    0.2748  0.4585
4   4       1620864000000   1.5669  1.9719  1.5000  1.9296  1.567655e+09    0.4719  0.7467
5   360     1651622400000   0.7712  0.8992  0.7677  0.8985  2.566498e+08    0.1315  0.6034
6   361     1651708800000   0.8986  0.9058  0.7716  0.7884  3.649706e+08    0.1342  0.2657
7   362     1651795200000   0.7884  0.7997  0.7625  0.7832  2.440587e+08    0.0372  0.1714
8   363     1651881600000   0.7832  0.7858  0.7467  0.7604  1.268089e+08    0.0391  0.0763
9   364     1651968000000   0.7605  0.7663  0.7254  0.7403  1.751395e+08    0.0409  0.0800
```

Comment: This did not work or maybe I am making a rookie mistake:

a['atrsum'] = a.expanding(14)['atr1'].sum()
The sum of the last 14 rows is giving me 49.2296, but it should be 0.8823

Comment: sorry @adsjr, I may have misunderstood the question then. I just added the result i received when summing two previous days.

Comment: I think it was just the position of ['atr1']. You suggested first a.expanding(14)['atr1'].sum() and now you tried with df['atr1'].expanding(2).sum()

Comment: It is giving me a different result I don't know why. Still in the order of 48-49 although your printout shows right

Comment: @adsjr, I tried it with 2, since I have a small data set and what works with 2 will work with 14

Comment: you're welcome @adsjr, i updated the answer with the rolling sum as well. for completeness

Answer (score 0):

At least for me the answer from Naveed did not work, but I found a different way:

```
a['atrsum']= a['atr1'].rolling(window=14).apply(sum).dropna()
```

This gives me the result.